# webpack DefinePlugin process.env.NODE_ENV is undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I am not too good with front-end technologies... So if I have wrong expectations - please correct me or my code. I have created a repository with code that allows to reproduce issue. Here is the link:
https://github.com/ffatheranderson/webpack-issue-reproduction

as described in readme.md of the project:

========================================

- **What I expect?** - I expect that after I execute `npm run watch` command - the generated
  `result/bundle.js` file to have such lines:

```
...
var _environment = 'development';
var _ANOTHER_VARIABLE = "another variable value";
...
```

- **What is actual result?** - after I execute `npm run watch` command - the generated
  `result/bundle.js` file contains such lines:

```
...
var _environment = undefined;
var _ANOTHER_VARIABLE = "another variable value";
...
```

- **Why do I have such expectations?** - because of these lines:

```
...
  plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            ENVIRONMENT: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
            ANOTHER_VARIABLE: JSON.stringify("another variable value"),
        })
    ]
...
```

in `webpack.config.js` file.

As you can see variable `_environment` is not initialized with `development` value as it is promised
here: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/

========================================

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_environment` is `undefined` because the environment variable `NODE_ENV` is undefined.  You can solve this in one of three:

1. Invoking `npm run watch --node-env=development`: https://webpack.js.org/api/cli/#node-env
2. Exporting `NODE_ENV` in your current shell session:

   ```sh
   $ export NODE_ENV=production; npm run watch
   ```
3. Updating your configuration to specify the value from some other source (e. g. an `--env` argument, a file on disk, hard-coding it, etc.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your complete answer. I used first offered by you solution. 
Why does this page: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/
 says:
Quote "Sets process.env.NODE_ENV on DefinePlugin to value development. Enables useful names for modules and chunks." ? To me it sounds like if I pass --mode=development, then it suppose to set process.env.NODE_ENV to development also. What am I missing here if you know?

Comment: Webpack _does_ set `process.env.NODE_ENV` _in the define plugin_.  That is webpack doesn't mutate the value of `process.env` _in the NodeJS process_ (which is what you are using to set `ENVIRONMENT`, it just looks for `process.env.NODE_ENV` **in the source code that webpack is processing** and replaces that.

Comment: I see. Thank you for explanation. To me it feels like documentation should explain it better, since in documentation it states that it "sets" it. 

Comment: I agree, it's definitely confusing.